# prove a polynomial identity..

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics

The equation is that

$h_m(x_1, \cdots, x_n, a)-h_m(x_1, \cdots, x_n, b)=(a-b)h_{m-1}(x_1, \cdots, x_n, a, b)$ where $h_m$ is a complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial.

See and find several examples then yes, it looks obvious, though I don't know how to prove the identity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that we have
$$
 h_m(x_1, \dotsc, x_n, y_1, \dotsc, y_k)
 = \sum_{i=0}^m h_{m-i}(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) h_i(y_1, \dotsc, y_k).
$$

We thus have
$$
 h(x_1, \dotsc, x_n,a) = \sum_{i=0}^m h_{m-i}(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) a^i.
$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
 &\, h(x_1, \dotsc, x_n,a) - h(x_1, \dotsc, x_n,b) \\
=&\, \sum_{i=1}^m h_{m-i}(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) (a^i-b^i)  \\
=&\, (a-b) \sum_{i=1}^m h_{m-i}(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)
           \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} a^{i-1-j} b^j.
\end{align*}
Now we finish with
\begin{align*}
&\, \sum_{i=1}^m h_{m-i}(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} a^{i-1-j} b^j
= \sum_{i=1}^m h_{m-i}(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) h_{i-1}(a,b) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} h_{m-1-i}(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) h_i(a,b)
= h(x_1, \dotsc, x_n, a, b).
\end{align*}